# Проигрывание музыки в Java Swing

Tags: java, аудио

Подскажите пожалуйста механизмы, библиотеки для работы со звуками, а именно проигрывание аудио mp3 и т.д. Хотелось бы чтобы была возможность проигрывания в отдельном потоке.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Для проигрывания *mp3* файлов можете использавать:
[mp3spi](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html) + [jLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/documents.html).
И в данном случае не имеет значение какие графические *libraries* ты используешь буть то AWT, Swing или JavaFX.

Вот [пример](https://github.com/gvart/RRPlayer) использования JavaFX + Spring Boot + mp3spi